Contact us form using Google Sheets and Apps Script
i updated the code now its working but
unable to send email to receiver and sender(copy of email) with all data entered in form(name,email,phone,message,file)
I tryied to write code in Apps Script for making contactus form.
Here is whats not working:

i tryed to add feature like if user submit form the email send to receiver email address as well sender(copy of email). but didnt worked so i removed that code part please implement this feature.
here is what i tryed to send email



MailApp.sendEmail({ to: receiver_email@gmail.com, to: formObject.email,
 subject: "message submited",
 body: "name,email,phone,messsage,file" });




and i noticed there is time delay after submiting form to show success message. so i tryed to show loading animation in that during time delay.
here is code i tryed for loading animation but unable to implement in html because i wrote css seperately thats the problem



$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myform").on("submit", function(){
    $("#preloder").fadeIn();
  });//submit
});//document ready
/* Preloder */

#preloder {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999999;
    /* background: #000; */
    background: #ffffff;
}

.loader {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    animation: loader 0.8s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: loader 0.8s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes loader {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;      
        /* border: 4px solid #f44336; */
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;
        /* border: 4px solid #673ab7; */
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loader {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Page Preloder -->
<div id="preloder">
    <div class="loader"></div>
</div>

<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>



Here is code i tryed to add loading animation to show loading animation during timedelay after submiting form to show success message (i am using swal.fire() to show success message)and tryed to add email sending feature in this appscript but unable to achive: (Two file 'code.js' & 'index.html')

code.js :



function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()
  .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
}

var url = '#'
var sh = 'file1'
var folderId = '#'

function processForm(formdata) {
  var superscript = SuperScript.initSuper(url, sh);
  var formObject = {};
  formdata.forEach(element => formObject[element.name] = element.value);
  formdata.forEach(element => formObject[element.message] = element.value);
  formdata.forEach(element => formObject[element.email] = element.value);
  formdata.forEach(element => formObject[element.phone] = element.value);

  var f = formdata.find(({ name }) => name == "myfile");
  var file = (f && f.value?.name && f.value?.data) ? superscript.uploadFile(folderId, formObject.myfile.data, formObject.myfilename) : "";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheets()[0];
  ws.appendRow([
    new Date(),
    formObject.name,
    "'" + formObject.message,
    formObject.email,
    formObject.phone,
    file && file.getUrl()
  ]);

}



and 2. index.html :


<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container py-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-8 mx-auto shadow border bg-white p-4 rounded">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" fw-bold mb-3>WRITE YOUR QUERY / MESSAGE</a>
                </nav>
                <br>
                <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit()">
                    <div id="form_alerts"></div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter your Name here|" name="name"required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <label for="email" >Email</label>
                        <input type="email"  class="form-control" id="email"
            placeholder="Enter your email address here|" name="email" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group mb-3">
           <label for="phone">phone number</label>
  <input type="tel" id="phone" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number here with country code|" pattern="[+]{1}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{10}" required>
  <small>requested example Format: +919263943858</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group mb-3">
              <label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Write your message here|" name="message" required ></textarea>
              </div>

                         <div class="form-group mb-3">
                            <label for="uploadFile">Upload File</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" File="file" id="file">
              <small>For multiple/bigger file size please attach/share via google drive link in message section.</small>
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" class= "btn btn-primary btn-block">SEND</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <script>
        function preventFormSubmit() {
                var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
                for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
                    forms[i].addEventListener('submit',
                     function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });
                }
            }
            window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);
            function handleFormSubmit() {
                var formdata = $('#myForm').serializeArray()
                formdata.push({
                  name: 'myfile',
                  value: myfile
                })
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).processForm(formdata);
            }
            function success(){
                 document.getElementById("myForm").reset()
                 Swal.fire({
                  position: 'center',
                  icon: 'success',
                  title: 'Sended successfully! Be ready we will contact you shortly',
                  showConfirmButton: true,
      
                })
            }
        var myfile ={},file, reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function(e) {
          myfile.data = e.target.result
          myfile.name = file.name
          console.log(myfile)
      };
     $('#file').change(function(){
       file = $('#file')[0].files[0]
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     })
    </script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
  <script src="sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




All three of those form fields are named in uppercase, Name etc., but then you try to access formObject.name on the receiving end - which should probably be formObject.Name instead?

yes name field working but other email and message field not working

Did you modify the code where you try to access those two as well ...?

i updated code now its working but email sending feature is not working and also i unable to add code(because i wrote css seperately i unable to implement in single html), to show loading animation between timedelay after submiting form and showing success message.

Try this Approach
In line with @C3roe, this means you need to match the Id , name in the attribute that you're using in appendRow.
Code.gs
sheet.appendRow([
  new Date(),
  formObject.name,
  formObject.message,
  formObject.email
]);

index.html
<form id="myForm">
   <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Name here" required>
  <label for="message" class="form-label">Message</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Message" required>
  <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label><br>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Email" required>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">SEND</button>
 </div>
                        
</form>

Code.gs
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate()
    .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function processForm(formObject) {
  try {
    var sheetId = 'SpreadsheetId'; 
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getActiveSheet();
    
    Logger.log("Form Data: ", formObject);
    
    
    sheet.appendRow([
      new Date(),
      formObject.name,
      formObject.message,
      formObject.email
    ]);

    return "Form submitted successfully";
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error: " + error.message);
    return "Error: " + error.message;
  }
}

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
          integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
          crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  
 <div class="container py-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-8 mx-auto shadow border bg-white p-4 rounded">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WRITE YOUR Query/Message</a>
        </nav>
        <br>
 <form id="myForm">
   <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Name here" required>
  <label for="message" class="form-label">Message</label><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Message" required>
  <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label><br><br>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Email" required>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">SEND</button>
 </div>
                        
</form>

<script>
  document.getElementById('myForm').onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData(this);

  
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
      alert(response);
      document.getElementById('myForm').reset();
    }).processForm(Object.fromEntries(formData));
  };
</script>

</body>
</html>

Sample Output
FrontEnd output

Spreadsheet

PS. I didn't include the file uploading. because the priority is on the Name, Message, and Email. The file upload feature is already working.
Reference

appendRow(rowContents)


code didnt worked as axpected

these three issue need to solve to make is fully working. if one thing solve other not working its interconnected very difficult to codeing.Here is whats not working:
after submiting the success message not showing (i am using 'swal.fire()' ).
and without uploading file , the all data for name,email,message are not getting visible in google sheet ,even i didnt set upload file as required.
additional i tryed to add feature like if user submit form the email notify send to receiver email address. but didnt worked so i removed that code part please inplement this feature as well . thanks

Hi, what is the specific part that is not working on your end as expected.
Please focus on one specific question at a time. If you have additional questions, kindly post them in a separate thread so we can address each issue clearly.

hi , i updated code now its working but email sending feature is not working and also i unable to add code(because i wrote css seperately i unable to implement in single html), to show loading animation between timedelay after submiting form and showing success message.
